# angular ionic $http service not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Loading json using $http isn't working. Can't figure out where the problem is

```
.factory('streamStore', function ($http) {
    var cachedData = null;

    return {
        findAll: function getAll() {
            $http.get('img/sample.json').
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("inside stream controller");
                    cachedData = data; return cachedData;
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // log error
                });
        }
```

And in my controller this is how I'm calling it:

```
.controller('streamCtrl', function ($scope, ,streamStore) {
    $scope.streams = streamStore.findAll();//not working ,
```

Comment: show the error msz ?

Comment: why not just returning data;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a error in your code . Check below

```
.factory('streamStore', function ($http) {

 var cachedData = null;

 return {
    findAll: function() {
        $http.get('img/sample.json').
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("inside stream controller");
                cachedData = data;
                return cachedData;
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // log error
            });
    }
```

and then call , as you were calling in your controller.

or use this

```
.factory('streamStore', function ($http) {

 var cachedData = function(){
     return $http.get('img/sample.json');
 };

 return {
    findAll: function(){
        return cachedData();
       }
    }

});
```

then in controller

```
streamStore.findAll().then(function(response){
     console.log(response) // here is your data
})
```

Comment: i use the above method, replace the console log with $scope.streams i get a error -TypeError: streamStore.findAll(...).then is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (app.js:34)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:13012)

Comment: tanks ,second method works can i pass argument to cachedata(userid) say to fetch spefic user id `return cacheData(userid)` along with the controller `streamStore.findAll(userid)`

Comment: yes you can do that and change your request type accrodingly

Answer (score 1):

since you have not returned anything from factory.

```
.factory('streamStore', function ($http) {
    var cachedData = null;

    return {
        findAll: function getAll() {
            $http.get('img/sample.json').
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("inside stream controller");
                    cachedData = data; return cachedData;

                     // should return something 
                     return cachedData
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // log error
                });
        }
```

one more suggestion return promise to make it safe .

```
return $http.get('img/sample.json')...
```

and handle with `then` in `controller`.

```
.controller('streamCtrl', function ($scope, ,streamStore) {
   streamStore.findAll().then(function(res){
         //res will contain your data 
         $scope.streams =  res.data;
     });
```

Comment: thanks for your suggesttion , the problem is im returning alot of function using the return { findAll,post,findOne ...} do u get the idea ,so i can call to any of the function in the controller ;